# $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] equivalents in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file

what is equivalents to `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` of PHP in C#.net?

Comment: If that is a method to get a temporary file, then you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

Comment: this seems to be related to uploading files - did a quick search. Seems like [FileUpload server control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx] is an option

Comment: why do you comment when you don't know what you are talking about?

Comment: @jgauffin because they were trying to help

Comment: @Rune FS: Yes, I do understand that. But anyone knowing PHP knows that the OPs code is not about trying to get any temp filename, but the filename used during the upload process. And the FileUpload Server control do not expose the temp filename either. So the "help" is just cluttering the question (and so is my rant)

Comment: @jgauffin which is way it would have been a good idea if OP had explained what he was trying to do instead of how to do it in another language.

Comment: @Rune FS: Why? The question is ***very*** clear to someone who knows PHP and ASP.NET. If you don't understand question, simply do not answer. It's also a clear indication to the OP if he do not get any answers.

Comment: @jgauffin that's funny if it's clear why are you you're self guessing at what he wants to accomplish? the code simply get's the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server. Still you are guessing  that he wants to save the file. There's no where in your code you accomplish the equivalent of OPs code

Comment: @Rune FS: I might have exaggerated a bit ;) But you get my point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent in ASP.NET is:

```
Request.Files["file"].SaveAs("Your filename");
```

ASP.NET do not expose the temporary filename which is used during the file upload.

If you want to validate the contents of the file you could read from `Request.Files["file"].InputStream`.

More information at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you mean APS.NET there is no such analog. But why you really need it?

in asp.net you can use HtmlInputFile control and then check it PostedFile property

```
HtmlInputFile filMyFile;
if( filMyFile.PostedFile != null )
{
    // File was sent
    HttpPostedFile file=filMyFile.PostedFile;
}
else
{
    // No file

}
```

Look more detail on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx)